# Quick proof regarding a question regarding the open, closed, etc. property of sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I was hoping that you guys can confirm that my rough working is correct over the following question:

Let $S$ be the set defined as
$$
S = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl( \frac1{n+1}, \frac1n \biggr)
$$

My guess is that $S$ is not closed as $0 \notin S$, but it is open.

The set of all limit points is $L = \{0\}$, the set of all isolated points of $S$ is itself, and the closure is simply $\bar{S} = S \cup L$.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: $\frac1n$ is a limit point for each natural number $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s true that $0$ is a limit point of $S$ that isn’t contained in $S$, so $S$ is not closed (in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology). It’s also true that $S$ is open since its complement is closed.

But there are more limit points than just $0$ (and no isolated points at all). Why?

Hint: $S$ consists of the open interval with the reciprocals of natural numbers removed:
$$
S = (0, 1) \setminus \bigl\{ \tfrac1n \bigm\vert n \in \mathbb{N} \bigr\}.  
$$

Comment: Yes, that's a correct definition of isolated point. But every point in the set is in one of the subintervals, hence is a limit point.